# Nullable in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nullable

Is there a way to make nullable struct in objective C like in C# you can use `Nullable<T>`?
I need a `CGPoint` to be `null` when there is no applicable value. I cannot allocate a random invalid value for this like `(-5000, -5000)` because all values are valid for this.

Answer (score 8):

What if you define a CGPoint using CGPointMake(NAN, NAN) similar to CGRectNull?  Surely with NAN's for coordinates, it's not still a valid point.

Comment: +1, I like this solution the best since it's simple and doesn't involve any objects.

Answer (score 3):

CGPoint is a struct and that has some different rules in objective-c than you might think. You should consider reading about structs in objective-c.

The way this is done most of the time is to wrap the struct in an object because that object can be set to null. NSValue will wrap a CGPoint.

```
NSValue * v = [NSValue valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(1,9)];
NSVAlue * vNull = [NSValue valueWithPointer:nil];
if([v objCType] == @encode(CGPoint)) printf("v is an CGPoint");
```

Answer (score 1):

CGPoint is a enum, not an object. You can use CGPointZero, or you can wrap all of your points inside of NSValue, which are objects and can be nil.

Comment: CGPoint is a struct, not an enum

Comment: No its not. in CGGeometry.h:

    `struct CGPoint {
      CGFloat x;
      CGFloat y;
    };`

Comment: Apart from CGPoint being a struct, the point of the OP is to have a value denoting *"invalid point"* and CGPointZero simply is a point with `x=0, y=0` which is perfectly valid.

Comment: Sorry about the typo with the struct vs. enum, but the point is still the same. It's not an object.

Answer (score 0):

There is also nothing stopping you creating your own struct based on CGPoint, similar to how C# 2 works.

```
struct NilableCGPoint { bool isNil; CGPoint point; }
```

Examples of use:

```
// No value (nil)
NilableCGPoint myNilablePoint.point = CGPointZero;
myPoint.isNil = YES;

// Value of (0,0)
NilableCGPoint myNilablePoint.point = CGPointZero;
myPoint.isNil = NO;

// Value of (100, 50)
NilableCGPoint myNilablePoint.point = CGPointMake(100, 50);
myPoint.isNil = NO;
```